# Determine what has taken up disk space on a retina MacBook in the last 24-48 hours?

Tags: mac, disk-space, macbook-air, macbook-pro-retina

MacBook is out of space again: 20GB free yesterday, now 0.

Is there a way to locate what has taken up the disk space in the last 24-48 hours?

Comment: Do you use Time Machine? Could be [local snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204015) though I'd really try to keep more than 20GB of free space on a drive

Comment: I use a program called OmniDiskSweeper.  While it won't tell you what files were created recently, it IS similar to WinDirStat, and will scan thru every file/folder on your hard drive and order them according to size.  From there, you should be able to click through and see what is taking up space and where.